# Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:

Tags: pandas, numpy, machine-learning, data-science, linear-regression

I used to built the model with Linear Regression by tuning the parameter using GridSearchCV.
In case of finding a score, i cant able to find that . It shows,

```
array=[1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1]
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

I used the code.

```
model.score(y_pred,y_test)
```

whats the problem is this!!!
and model.score(takes which type of data)

y_pred is an single dimensinal array that gives from the regressor. but it cant take into the score function. what can i do? and what the solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have switched the arguments.

The `.score()` function takes at least two arguments. The first one is an array-like of whatever input format you need (in this case `(n_examples, n_features)`, the second is an array-like of shape `(n_examples,)` containing the correct target outputs corresponding to those inputs.

When in doubt, look in the documentation. In this case, the docstring of `.score()` would have helped you locate your problem.